# Internal Server error using Bash Terminal, any idea why is it throwing this error and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, git-bash

I have just recently started learning about APIs as party of Full stack developer course. Everything has been working fine until I have activated system storage sense in Windows to clear some space in the disk /c, the curl command stopped working and is giving internal server error.

[curl calling request error using bash terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZPh0.png)

I have realized there is an issue when I have run my code and it stopped pulling information from the API link.

Comment: Because of the & you will probably need to put the URL in quotation marks. Perhaps this already the cause of the server side error: missing parameters. You have to check the server log for errors, post them as *text* not *images*

Answer (score 0):

Since you made a windows change my guess would be - try addding the curl folder path to your Windows PATH environment variable so that the curl command is available from any location at the command prompt.

Comment: The error is coming from curl, so it could be loaded and there is no problem with the path